# Angular 9 (or 2+) does not detect CHANGES, if injected via | async, on the parent's HTML [Input()], if they are too fast - hundreds of milliseconds

Tags: angular, pipe, observable, angular-changedetection, ngonchanges

I have an Observable giving me some log changes (sometimes *hundreds* per **milisecond**).
I subscribe to this Observable, on `ngOnInit()` and can console ALL the changes beautifully.

Problem comes when i `pipe async` this Observable into an HTML `@Input()` of a child Component -  if the Observable, on the parent, sees its scalar value changing on parts of miliseconds... which it does, in fact, **no change detection** happens, on the Child component.

This Observable of mine is a **simple string**, timestamped to 1/1000 (as the browser's console.log).
So, this case of mine has nothing to do with `Array`s or `Object`s that can be *the same* and, in fact, might not triger any change...

Any sugestions?
Thank you so much!

By the way this is for an Angular application trying to log everything that is hapening on the re-rendering, and re-mounting, of a **3D Components** `Scene`, talking to the `ThreeJS` library.
You can imagine the speed...

A bit of the envoled code.

`logger.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggerService {

    public newEvtLogged$ = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() { }

    addLog(log: string) {
        const timeStamp = this.returnNowsTime();
        const loggedEvt = `@ ${timeStamp}: ${log}`;

        this.newEvtLogged$.next(loggedEvt);
    }

...

    /**
     * We want to simulate the broser'd Inspector timestamp.
     * A kind of an unique Id could be '#${new Date().getTime()}'
     * But we want user to see when the event happened...
     */
    private returnNowsTime(): string {
        const now = new Date();
        return now.toLocaleTimeString() + '.' + now.getMilliseconds();

    }

}
```

`parent-component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-menu',
    templateUrl: './component-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-menu.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ComponentMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {

...

    // NgRxJS stream of added logg events, through LoggerService, all over the App:
    loggEvent$: Observable<string>;
    loggSubscription: Subscription;
    loggEvent: string;

...

    ngOnInit() {

        this.loggEvent$ = this.THreeJSloggerService.newEvtLogged$;

        // Check we're subscribing from the beginning:
        this.loggSubscription = this.loggEvent$.subscribe((logEvt: string) => {
            console.log('$$$$$$$$ NEW LOGG EVENT: ', logEvt);
            this.loggEvent = logEvt;
        });
    }
```

`parent-component.html`

```
<ng3d-monitor-debug [goToTopPosition]="monitorMarginTop" [dataToPrint]="(loggEvent$ | async)"></ng3d-monitor-debug>
```

`child-component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ng3d-monitor-debug',
    templateUrl: './monitor-debug.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./monitor-debug.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MonitorDebugComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

    ...

    @Input() dataToPrint: string;

    ...

    constructor(
        private hostElement: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        ...
    }

    ngOnChanges(propsChanged: SimpleChanges) {
        // console.error(propsChanged);

        if (propsChanged.dataToPrint && !propsChanged.dataToPrint.firstChange) {
            // console.error('=============== dataToPrint has CHANGED:', this.dataToPrint);

            this.doPrintData(this.dataToPrint, null);
        }

    }

    ...

    private doPrintData(str: string, jsonData: any) {
        this.contentHTMLmsg =  jsonData ? str + this.prettyPrintJson(JSON.stringify(jsonData, undefined, 4)) : str;

        const contentOrigStripped = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');               // <= strips from ALL HTML tags...
        const contentStripped = this.contentHTMLmsg.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');

        console.error('SHOULD PRINT (resumed):', contentOrigStripped.slice(contentOrigStripped.length - 40));
    }

}
```

And here, the console **results** (5 missings, though the subscription `$$$$$$$$` gets them):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: post some code that demonstrates the problem.  Hard to help if you show no code.

Comment: I'll try.... App is huge and complex. But I'll try a simple case.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a conception problem. Even if you manage to force Angular detecting your change, you'll only trigger one ngOnChange per parent's life-cycle, not 1 per millisec as the observable triggers. You should either give the observable to your child (which would subsribe to it), or make your child subscribe to the observable via a service.

Comment: Looks fair enough @Random.  I knew it was an Angular *issue*... But as you put it, can not be considered a bug but, as you so well classified it, a conception problem - because of the necessary times, for Angular, far superior than *miliseconds*...  I'll try your approach and come back here. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, @Brandom, sample code is posted.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for the perfect editing !.

Answer (score 0):

Things are not so simple, when we have **changes** of milliseconds...

I was doing a lot of testings, following your thoughts, and I think Angular has a problem relating the component's life cycle hooks and the changes on its `@Input()`s.

Regarding `parent-component.html`:

Try 1:

```
<ng3d-monitor-debug [goToTopPosition]="monitorMarginTop"></ng3d-monitor-debug>
```

Try 2:

```
<ng3d-monitor-debug [goToTopPosition]="monitorMarginTop" [dataToPrint]="loggEvent"></ng3d-monitor-debug>
```

Try 3, and last one, that proove to work:

```
<ng3d-monitor-debug [goToTopPosition]="monitorMarginTop" [dataToPrint]="(loggEvent$ | async)"></ng3d-monitor-debug>
```

So:
On **try 1**, the Child Component is getting the logged strings directly from `this.THreeJSloggerService.newEvtLogged$;` `subject`. No `@Input()`.
**Results**:
While on mounting, the Child component clearly did its job: logged messages are rendered on the Template var `contentHTMLmsg`.
But, after mounting, logged strings start to disappear...

On **try 2**, we have a plain **scalar** value passed in, coming from parent's subscribing to the `this.THreeJSloggerService.newEvtLogged$;` `subject`.
**Results**:
No entire rendering of Template var `contentHTMLmsg` (screen just got freezed!) on mounting the Child and, after the `ngOnChanges()`, missings still happen.

On **try 3** I have tried a crazy thing, that thought would never work - but it did!
Get the logged strings, while the Child component is being mounted, from the Service `Subject`, by subscribing to it, and then, once Child's mounting has finished, since the subscrition to the same `Subject` was still active from the Parent, the **pipe** `[dataToPrint]="(loggEvent$ | async)"`was being catched, this time, by the Child's `ngOnChanges()`!
And echoing, perfectly, on the Child's Template variable `contentHTMLmsg`. ;-)

One obviously problem arised: after mounting, I was seeing **duplicated** msgs... the one sent by the Child's subscription and the second one by the Parent's one.

"So... now it works? On both cycles...?" - was my thought
Yes!

So, keeping the Parent's HTML (i.e. conserving the Child's `@Input()` pipe **AND** the logged msgs `subscription`), I just ***commented*** the ngOnChanges() code, of the Child, that was echoing the ghost msgs - and duplicate rendering of logged msgs don't exist anymore.

And all is good!

My theory is:
As long as you declare an injection of an @Input(), even if you don't care for it on the Child's `ngOnChanges()`, just because it's a declared entrance, and **for very fast changes**, Angular will still look for changes, on the same variable, even if they come from other source - NOT from the `@Input()`.

Ah! One more thing.
Angular feels a certain *pain* when we play with him this game... the error consoled is not a surprise:
`ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '@ 03:31:44.353: ====== RENDERing of an Object done!Orbit Control initialization'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?"`

It's thrown JUST before all the mounting finishes.

The real live proof can be seen here:
http://ng3d.miles-net.com/obj
One thing:
this is something I'm still working on... so far, no "loading wheels" and for you to see the '3 floor Office"' 3D building, you have to wait between 30 secs to 1 minute - depends highly on the machine.

But the important thing is to see each logged msg getting printed on the monitor, and timmings can be also inspected.
After all... it is an Angular *issue*! I repeat, when we're dealing with millisecs changes.

What are your thoughts on this...?
Thank you very much @Random!